# Find word near other word, within N# of words

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I need an enumerating regex function that identifies instances in a string when 'Word 1' is within ***N***# words of 'Word 2'

For example, here is my dataframe and objective:

**Pandas Dataframe Input**

```
data = [['ABC123', 'This is the first example sentence the end of 
sentence one'], ['ABC456', 'This is the second example sentence one more 
sentence to come'], ['ABC789', 'There are no more example sentences']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Record ID', 'String'])
print(df)

Record ID | String
----------|-----------------------
ABC123    | This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one
ABC456    | This is the second example sentence one more sentence to come
ABC789    | There are no more example sentences
```

Word 1 = 'sentence' 
Word 2 = 'the' 
Within ***N***# of words (displaced) = 3

**Desired Dataframe Output**

```
output_data = [['ABC123', 3], ['ABC456', 1], ['ABC789', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['Record ID', 'Occurrences Identified'])
print(df)

Record ID | Occurrences Identified
----------|-----------------------
ABC123    | 3
ABC456    | 1
ABC789    | 0
```

I think the regex part will take the general form of this, but I'm not sure how to apply it towards my use-case here in Python and ... I'm not sure where to start with a enumerate function.

```
\b(?:'sentence'\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?'the'|'the'\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?'sentence')\b
```

I am also interested in simpler non-regex solutions, if any.

```
Data = pd.read_sql(query, engine)

# Convert to Pandas DataFrame
nearwordDF = pd.DataFrame(Data)

# Remove non-alpha characters and make all lowercase
nearwordDF['text'] = nearwordDF['text'].str.replace(',', ' ')
nearwordDF['text'] = nearwordDF['text'].str.replace('.', '')
nearwordDF['text'] = nearwordDF['text'].str.replace('?', '')
nearwordDF['text'] = nearwordDF['text'].str.replace('\r', '')
nearwordDF['text'] = nearwordDF['text'].str.lower()

print(nearwordDF)
--------------------------
id        text
ABC123    how much money do i have in my money account
ABC456    where is my money
ABC789    hello  how are you today what is your name
DEF123    my money market fund is my only money of my account

import re
import pandas as pd

output = []
for i in nearwordDF:
    regex = r'(?:my(?:\s\w+){0,2})\s(?=money)|(?:money(?:\s\w+){0,2})\s(?=my)'
    nearwordDF = re.findall(regex, i[1])
    output.append([i[0], len(nearwordDF)])

df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['Record ID', 'Occurrences'])
print(df)

-----------------------------------
# Output
Record ID    Occurrences
i            0
t            0
```

Comment: can you explain why `ABC123` got 3 occurences?

Comment: @Ramesh sure, no problem. 
Here's a visual of why for each record:
https://imgur.com/hMpHIBn

Comment: `This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one` in this text we have only 2 occurences `the` and `sentence` is that correct?

Comment: @Ramesh There are three occurrences: (1) "the first example sentence", (2) "sentence the", (3) "the end of sentence". (1) and (2) are overlapping.

Comment: @Ramesh yes, affirmative. Is there a way to close-out this question as "solved" or should I just share the preferred solution with you in a message?

Comment: If the question is solved then "accept" the answer with the solution. If none of the existing answers are correct or sufficient then please write a complete answer and accept it. See the [help] pages for more info about accepting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe regex is not the right solution here.

If you split your input string into a list, you can then locate the indices of words 1 and 2, and calculate how far away they are from each other:

```
string = 'This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one'
string_list = string.split(' ')
indices_word_1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == "sentence"]
indices_word_2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == "the"]
result = 0
for i in indices_word_1:
    for j in indices_word_2:
        _distance = abs(i - j)
        if _distance <= 3:
            result += 1
```

In this case the result is 3.

@tshobe, here is one way to implement my suggestion:

```
import pandas


def check_occurences(string, word_1='sentence', word_2='the', allowed_distance=3):
    string_list = string.split(' ')
    indices_word_1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == word_1]
    indices_word_2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == word_2]
    result = 0
    for i in indices_word_1:
        for j in indices_word_2:
            _distance = abs(i - j)
            if _distance <= allowed_distance:
                result += 1
    return result


def main():
    data = [['ABC123', 'This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one'],
        ['ABC456', 'This is the second example sentence one more sentence to come'],
        ['ABC789', 'There are no more example sentences']]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Record ID', 'String'])

    results_df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Record ID', 'Occurrences'])

    results_df['Record ID'] = df['Record ID']
    results_df['Occurrences'] = df['String'].apply(lambda x: check_occurences(x))

    print(results_df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's a nice solution using enumerate and index :).

Comment: How do I use this on a pre-existing Pandas Dataframe with a specific column for the string? When I run this nothing happens, it doesn't return anything. Do I use this at the beginning? 

string_list = pandasDF['Column Name'].str.split(' ')

Also, how do I get the output in the format I'm needing, where its a new dataframe with two columns (Record ID and Occurrences Identified) ?

Comment: My answer shows a logical way of solving your problem, but indeed it doesn't show you how to implement it. I will try to edit my comment with an implementation.

Comment: @tshobe please see my solution, I added an implementation

Answer (score 1):

you can use positive look ahead `(?=)` to the validate the word `sentence`.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
data = [['ABC123', 'This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one'],
        ['ABC456', 'This is the second example sentence one more sentence to come'],
        ['ABC789', 'There are no more example sentences']]
output = []
for i in data:
    regex = r'(?:the(?:\s\w+){0,2})\s(?=sentence)|(?:sentence(?:\s\w+){0,2})\s(?=the)'
    data = re.findall(regex, i[1])
    output.append([i[0], len(data)])
print(output)
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['Record ID', 'Occurrences Identified'])
print(df)
```

**output**

```
[['ABC123', 3], ['ABC456', 1], ['ABC789', 0]]

  Record ID  Occurrences Identified
0    ABC123                       3
1    ABC456                       1
2    ABC789                       0
```

Comment: This is great, but how and where exactly do I insert my pre-existing dataframe that's already been created? My data is already in Pandas Dataframe format and contains thousands of rows (from a SQL query). When I try to plug it into your code chunk here it just receive error messages like the length does not match or the 'Series' is not callable, or the output is just blank.

Comment: If the regex is working, you can add it to your sql select clause instead of querying your data and then running regex on your df from python.

Comment: I agree, but just for educational purpose, I would still like to know how to run this code based off a pre-existing dataframe, if you don't mind explaining that part. I will use it for later for other functions too.

Comment: can you add the code using the above regex.so that i can check the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were very close to the solution. The `'` in your regex match literal apostrophes. But you don't want to match apostrophes. If you remove them, you end up with a valid pattern:

```
>>> re.compile(r'\b(?:sentence\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?the|the\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?sentence)\b', re.I).finditer("This is the first example sentence the end of sentence one")
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 34), match='the first example sentence'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(35, 54), match='the end of sentence'>]
```

Note, this does only find two occurrences because regex matches don't overlap. If you need overlapping results, you probably better use another solution.