# Count number of times a phrase is near another phrase, within n# of words of each other

Tags: python, match-phrase

I need to count the number of times a specific phrase occurs within 3 words of another specific phrase, per row of a dataframe string. Order does not matter.

To illustrate: X = "black cat", Y = "is my", proximity distance = 3, and String = "***The black cat is my black cat***", .... the output count would be two (two unique pairs found). "***The black cat by the window is my black cat***" would also = two matches found. However, "***The black cat by the big window is my black cat***" = one match found.

Here is my example data, broken code, and desired output:

```
data = [['ABC123', 'test sentence here has these test words'], ['ABC456', 'test sentence here 
contains these test words in test sentence form'], ['ABC789', 'the third test sentence has no 
more additional test words']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Record ID', 'String'])
print(df)

Record ID | String
----------|-----------------------
ABC123    | test sentence here has these test words
ABC456    | test sentence here contains these test words in test sentence form
ABC789    | the third test sentence has no more additional test words


import pandas as pd  

def phrase_finder(df, text_column, search_phrase, near_phrase, distance):
results = 0
for text in df[text_column]:
    for substring in text.split(search_phrase):
        words = substring.split()
        if len(words) <= distance + 1 and near_phrase in substring:
            results += 1
return results if results else None

search_phrase = "test sentence"
near_phrase = "test words"
distance = 3

print(phrase_finder(df, 'String', search_phrase, near_phrase, distance))

ID        | Number of Matches
----------|-----------------------
ABC123    | 1
ABC456    | 2
ABC789    | 0
```

This is a direct follow-up to
[Find word near other word, within N# of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078466/find-word-near-other-word-within-n-of-words)

I was instructed to create a separate question for this rather than posting it on the other one as a follow-up.

Comment: How do we count cases like `X Y X` when looking for X within N words of Y?

Comment: @Lodinn Thank you for the question. We would want to count those a legitimate, unique/separate pairs. So, in your case, if X = "black cat", Y = "is my", proximity distance = 3 and then we encountered "The black cat is my black cat", .... the output count would be two (two unique pairs found).

Comment: @Lodinn my apologies, I misunderstood what you meant by X Y X. I didn't realize you were really asking about situations where the two phrases overlap (which I would annotate as "XY X" or "x/y X"). So, in that case, I would say no, I do not want to include any overlaps. The boundaries of X and Y must never overlap, I mean. Maybe I'll create a separate function for that later.

Comment: Duplicate to [Python | Pair Iteration List | Find position of "can" and "help" if they are within 3 words of each other in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142327/python-pair-iteration-list-find-position-of-can-and-help-if-they-are-wit)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar this is NOT a duplicate to the pair iteration question. That one tries to find the position of the instance, not the count of instances. Also, word is treated different than phrase.

Comment: @tshobe No, you got it right, that is what I meant initially. Overlaps are tricky, but if you don't care about them, my&Abhijit's approach (which are basically the same) seem to work well enough. You would need to define what a word is for splitting the part between regex matches (you could use `str.split` or split by `^\w` or something else depending on your application - consider constructions like `The black cat by,the,big,window.is my black cat` or `gene variant (rs10774671-G)` - how should you parse punctuation and numbers? Logic is still pretty much the same, but regexes change).

Comment: @Lodinn Although our implementations are similar, they aren't "_basically the same_", there's a difference. Consider a phrase `s` that is entirely made up of two phrases, `x` and `y`; So, `s = xyxy...`. Since you've a nested loop, your code will incur `O(mn)` cost, whereas mine will incur `O(m+n)`. `m` and `n` are the number of times `x` and `y` occur in `s`, respectively. This may not matter for the toy example in this post, but does matter for large `m` and `n`.

Comment: @tshobe The reason I consider your question to be a duplicate because seemingly you failed to grasp the crux of the exercise. The point is to _tokenize_ a given phrase `s`; whether those tokens are words, phrases or lines, it really doesn't change the algorithm. For words or lines, you'd just use a different regex. Having found the positions, it is trivial to compare them pairwise using any logic you want.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Good point. Yes, a single-pass algorithm is significantly better optimized (and, perhaps accordingly, reads a bit more like C to me); what I meant was that the key parts about tokenization work the same. Sorry.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That's not the crux of my exercise, maybe yours. I'm not married to a single method here. I'm here to explore all methods. Its already been pointed out the regex is suspected to be a suboptimal solution for one of my related questions. We can argue whether or not the core usage is the same, but the output objective is certainly not the same (Position vs Count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe O-O-O was somewhat right about regex - it is a major unsustainable PITA in your use case, IMHO. That said, the problem is quite tricky...

What regex does well is string tokenization. I have applied a rather straightforward approach:

1. Find all matches for substring 1
2. Find all matches for substring 2
3. Count words between these matches

Not sure what are we supposed to do if substrings overlap. The code is as follows. Just string slicing and word counting, no mindboggling magic here (the less magic in the production code, the better!):

```
import re

def phrase_finder(text: str, str1: str, str2: str, distance: int) -> int:
    results = 0
    for match1 in re.finditer(str1, text):
        for match2 in re.finditer(str2, text):
            if match1.end() < match2.start():
                between_matches = text[match1.end():match2.start()]
                if len(re.findall(r'\w+', between_matches)) <= distance:
                    results += 1
            elif match2.end() < match1.start():
                between_matches = text[match2.end():match1.start()]
                if len(re.findall(r'\w+', between_matches)) <= distance:
                    results += 1
            else:
                # what do we do here?
                pass
    return results
```

Test cases:

```
phrase_finder('The black cat is my black cat', 'black cat', 'is my', 3)
# 2
phrase_finder('The black cat by the window is my black cat', 'black cat', 'is my', 3)
# 2
phrase_finder('The black cat by the big window is my black cat', 'black cat', 'is my', 3)
# 1

import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

data = [
    ['', 0],
    ['A', 0],
    ['B', 0],
    ['A B', 1],
    ['B A', 1],
    ['A A B', 2],
    ['A B B', 2],
    ['A B C', 1],
    ['A C C C B', 1], 
    ['A C C C C B', 0], 
    ['A B A', 2], 
    ['A B A A', 3],
    ['A B A A A', 4],
    ['A B A B A', 6]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text', 'expected_output'])
df['result'] = df['text'].apply(partial(phrase_finder, str1=r'A', str2=r'B', distance=3))
df
#       text    expected_output result
# 0                 0               0
# 1     A           0               0
# 2     B           0               0
# 3     A B         1               1
# 4     B A         1               1
# 5     A A B       2               2
# 6     A B B       2               2
# 7     A B C       1               1
# 8     A C C C B   1               1
# 9     A C C C C B 0               0
# 10    A B A       2               2
# 11    A B A A     3               3
# 12    A B A A A   4               4
# 13    A B A B A   6               6
```

And it is symmetric as well.

There is one notable pitfall here, however:

```
phrase_finder(r'AA B A C AAA', r'A', r'B', 3)
# -> 6
```

The correct way to call it in this case is by supplying word boundaries for regexes (note the `r` prefix as well!):

```
phrase_finder(r'AA B A C AAA', r'\bA\b', r'\bB\b', 3)
# -> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def count_proximity(s, s1, s2, t):
  xs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(s1, s)]
  ys = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(s2, s)]
  
  count = i = j = 0
  while i < len(xs) and j < len(ys):
    x = xs[i]
    y = ys[j]
    if x <= y:
      count += int(len(s[x + len(s1) : y].split()) <= t)
      i += 1
    else
      count += int(len(s[y + len(s2) : x].split()) <= t)
      j += 1
  
  return count


s1 = "black cat"
s2 = "is my"
t = 3

for s in [
  "The black cat is my black cat",
  "The black cat by the window is my black cat",
  "The black cat by the big window is my black cat"
]:
  print(count_proximity(s, s1, s2, t))
```